# deployment war jboss-eap-6.4 failed

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jboss

It am getting errors when deploying war to Jboss-eap 6.4. Below is the error log, what could have possibly gone wrong?

> 14:48:04,446 INFO 
>   [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Fetching config from server at:
>   http://10.170.49.172/configserver 14:48:25,518 ERROR
>   [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 66) Application startup failed:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and
>   the fail fast property is set, failing    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
>   [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://10.170.49.172/configserver/crmservices/sit":
>   Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  ... 20
>   more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   connect   at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  ... 24 more
>
> 14:48:25,518 INFO 
>   [org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Application failed to start with
>   classpath: unknown 14:48:25,518 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 66) JBAS018202: Error calling onStartup for servlet
>   container initializer:
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and
>   the fail fast property is set, failing    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
>   [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://10.170.49.172/configserver/crmservices/sit":
>   Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81)
>   [spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]  ... 20
>   more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   connect   at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
>   [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  ... 24 more
>
> 14:48:25,581 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)
>   JBAS018206: Webapp [/cxf/crm] is unavailable due to startup errors
>   14:48:25,581 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 66) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /cxf/crm start,
>   will stop it 14:48:25,581 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
>     ... 6 more
>
> 14:48:25,596 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) -
>   failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context
>       Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}} 14:48:25,612 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859:
>   Deployed "crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name :
>   "crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war") 14:48:25,612 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859:
>   Deployed "crm-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name :
>   "crm-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar") 14:48:25,612 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service
>   status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:
>   service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context
>
> 14:48:25,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961:
>   Http management interface listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:9990/management 14:48:25,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:9990 14:48:25,737 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller
>   Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21)
>   started (with errors) in 30934ms - Started 316 of 357 services (2
>   services failed or missing dependencies, 62 services are lazy, passive
>   or on-demand) 14:48:26,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC
>   service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment
>   crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name:
>   crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 949ms 14:48:27,515 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858:
>   Undeployed "crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name:
>   "crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war") 14:48:27,515 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774:
>   Service status report JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied
>   dependencies:
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ArgumentTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag".START
> ```
>
> (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm (missing) dependents: [service
> ```
>
> jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>
> ```
>   service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm.realm (missing) dependents: [service
> ```
>
> jboss.deployment.unit."crm-services-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>   JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cxf/crm